# Python: How do i sort Names in a text file alphabetically?

Tags: python

my questions is, how to i sort by the 1st letter of the person's name in a text file(A at the top going to Z at the bottom). I use python 3.4.3.

**I have a text file containing names and scores: = ('test', ' ', 1)**
I've tried the code below however it doesn't seem to sort alphabetically.

`age` = class number

```
file = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "a")
file.write(name + " " + " {}\n".format(score))
f = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
lines.sort()
f = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "w")
for line in lines:
    f.write(line)
f.flush()
f.close()
print(lines)
```

Comment: Please post an example of input and expected output.

Comment: The user will input their name and class number and get a score /10. The text file will be created dependent on the class number. The users name followed by score will be written into the text file.

Comment: I want to sort it so that Alex, for instance, is on top on Michael, for example.

Comment: **please** post a **concrete example** of input and expected output.

Comment: So what is your question? Is there any problems? try `lines = lines.sort()`?

Comment: When i go into the text file created the names of people arnt listed in alphabetical order

Comment: built in sort() just do it. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @flyingpython what's so hard to understand about the "concrete example" words ? Please post **an example input file** (like the one you're using for your own tests) and **the matching expected output file**.

Comment: Give me an example of the code to add or edit my code please

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Sorry but i dont understand you

Comment: @flyingpython you're program reads a file (the input), sort the lines and write the sorted result to a file (the output). **Please** post your input file and an example of the expected output file for this given input file.

Comment: Read file --- Sort the names alphabetically --- save file

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably in your file. The code you posted works fine for a .txt file such as:

```
Dave = 12
Peter = 5
Agnes = 4
Charles = 10
Mary = 8
```

Please post your file.

Comment: Thank you very much, so that was the problem...thank you so much! :D

Comment: I know it should have been a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to write comments. I'm glad that it helped :).